# jQuery trying to get .attr({href: }) to send to a <div id= .....> further down the same webpage in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pagination

I haven't worked with jQuery for a while, that's why I'm here to ask this pretty simple question.

So I'm dynamically filling in a pagination script with page numbers that'll take a user down the page to a div with that specific id. For example:

```
<li class="page-item current-page active"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
<li class="page-item dots"><a class="page-link" href="#">...</a></li>
```

is supposed to take the user down the webpage to

`<div id="1" class="page-number"><div class="number">1</div></div>`

You'll notice above that the `href="#"`. I have to have it this way because the text `1` will accumulate to `2` and so on.

So I've been able to generate everything using the code below:

```
getPageList(totalPages, currentPage, paginationSize).forEach(item =>{
       $("<li>").addClass("page-item").addClass(item ? "current-page" : "dots")
       .toggleClass("active", item === currentPage).append($("<a>").addClass("page-link")
       .attr({href: "javascript:void(0)"}).text(item || "...")).insertBefore(".next-page")
```

You'll notice right now I have `.attr({href: "javascript:void(0)"})` as filler. I know this is wrong. What I want to do is get that `href` to equal the item's text. So again, the `1` the `2` and so on.

Some things I've tried:

```
.attr({href: item})
```

```
.attr({href: item.this})
```

```
.attr({href: this.item})
```

None work. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, can you show what `getPageList` does or what exactly your `item` has ?

Comment: _"What I want to do is get that href to equal the item's text"_ - why? `href="1"` would link to a relative URL, a "document" named `1` within the current folder. _"that'll take a user down the page to a div with that specific id"_ - the usual method to do that, is to use anchor links that target the ID, so `href="#id"`. If you are not doing that, then presumably you must have some additional JS involved, that handles the clicks on those links ...?

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert `#` at the beginning of the `href`:

```
.attr('href', '#' + item)
```

BTW, when you're initializing a bunch of attributes of an element when creating it, I've found this style easier to understand than all the chained method calls:

```
$("<ul>", {
    "class": `page-item ${item ? "current-page" : "dots"} ${item === currentPage ? "active" : ""}`,
    html: $("<a>", {
        href: "#" + item,
        "class": "page-link",
        text: item || "..."
    })
}).insertBefore(".next-page");
```

Comment: Big thanks, man! Also, please let me know how to upvote your account. I don't use Stackoverflow very often. Again, big thanks. It totally works.